# Is $C_b(Q,E)$ linearly isometrically isomorphic to $C(\beta Q,E)$ where $\beta Q$ is the Stone–Čech compactification of $Q$?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification

Let $Q$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $E$ be a Banach space.
Let $C(Q)$ be the collection of all real-valued continuous functions on $Q$ and $C_b(Q,E)$ be the collection of all $E$-valued bounded continuous functions on $Q$.

Clearly $Q$ is completely regular.
Let $\beta Q$ to be the Stone–Čech compactification, where $\beta Q = \overline{e(Q)}$ and $e:Q\to \prod_{f\in C_b(Q),[0,1])}[0,1]$ is an embedding.

> **Question**:
> Is $C_b(Q,E)$ linearly isometrically isomorphic to $C(\beta Q,E)?$

It is known that $C_b(Q)$ is linearly isometrically isomorphic to $C(\beta Q)$, thanks to the following proposition.
The following extension theorem is taken from Carothers's [A Short Course in Banach Space Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/short-course-on-banach-space-theory/88B71D535E744B24CA17CA82E670BFF4), Chapter 15 [Theorem 15.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=pec4r3EsIiMC&pg=PA149).

> **Theorem** 15.1: Every $f\in C_b(Q)$ extends to a continuous function $F:\beta Q\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $F\circ e = f$.

The theorem provides a linear isometry from $C_b(X)$ onto $C(\beta Q)$ by the mapping $F\mapsto F\circ e$.

However, I do not know whether there exists a Stone—Čech compactification for ‘Banach space-valued’ mappings, that is,

> **Question**: For every $f\in C_b(Q,E)$, does there exist a continuous extension $F:\beta Q\to E$ such that $F\circ e = f$?

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean for the extension $F$ to be continuous. Since its image is then compact, this can only happen if the image of $f$ is relatively compact. And this condition is sufficient by the universal property of the compactification.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edited.

Comment: Parschallen's answer means that the canonical map $\rho: C(\beta Q,E)\to C_b(Q,E)$, $f\mapsto f|_Q$ is hardly ever surjective: Continuous functions $\beta Q\to E$ have compact range but bounded continuous functions $f:Q\to E$ need not have compact range.

Comment: Then why would $C_b(Q)$ be linearly isometric isomorphic to $C(\beta Q),$ as the functions in latter set have compact range while the former may not.

Comment: In the one dimensional case, boundedness and relative compactness are the same thing.

Comment: @Parschallen Do you mean finite dimensional case? Because relative compactness always implies boundedness (as $A\subseteq \overline{A}$ and $\overline{A}$ is bounded). In finite dimensional case, bounded and totally bounded are equivalent notions and totally boundedness implies relative compact in a complete metric space.

Comment: @Parschallen How about if we assume that $E$ is reflexive?

Comment: It will only work for functions with relatively compact range. However, you can use weak compactness to get a continuous extension, just that continuity will be with respect to the weak topology and not (in general) the norm.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the point is that even if we know, after Jochen's [remark](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299715/is-c-bq-e-linearly-isometric-isomorphic-to-c-beta-q-e-where-beta-q-is#comment745809_299717), that the natural map $\rho:C(\beta Q,E)\to C_b(Q,E)$ fails to be onto it remains to see that these spaces are not isometric (under some "esoteric" isometry). This follows (in most cases) from classical stuff on tensor products and a result by Cembranos and Mendoza. Let us consider the case in which $Q=\mathbb N$ is infinite discrete and $E$ is an infinite dimensional, separable Hilbert space. The space $C_b(\mathbb N, E)$ consists of all bounded sequences in $E$ and, being isometric to the dual of $\ell_1(\mathbb N,E)$, cannot contain a complemented copy of $c_0$. The space $C(\beta\mathbb N, E)$ is isometric to the injective tensor product of $C(\beta N)=\ell_\infty$ and $E$ and (this is Cembranos–Mendoza's result) so it contains a complemented copy of $c_0$. Hence $C(\beta\mathbb N, E)$ and  $C_b(\mathbb N, E)$ cannot be linearly homeomorphic, let alone isometric.